# If a topological space $X$ has a countable basis. Then if we have an open cover of $X$, can this cover be refined to a countable one?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

If a topological space $X$ has a countable basis. Then if we have an open cover of $X$, can this cover be refined to a countable one?

Comment: Hint: Given an open cover $\{U_i\}$ of $X$, each $U_i$ is a union of basis elements, of which there are only countably many. Can you use this to pick countably many of the $U_i$ which still cover $X$?

Comment: So for a given set in the cover $U_i$, we know it is the union of countably many basis elements. Call this set $V_i$. So we can consider $\union_{i\in I} V_i$. This is a subset of our basis, which is countable. Hence countable. Hence the cover can be reduced to a countable one.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Fix $\cal B$ to be a countable basis. Let $\cal U$ be our open cover. For $U\in\cal U$ define $V_U=\{V\in\mathcal B\mid V\subseteq U\}$. Then $\mathcal V=\bigcup\{V_U\mid U\in\cal U\}$ is an open cover as well, but it is countable since it is a subset of $\cal B$.

You can show even more, you can actually get a countable subcover for $\cal U$. For every $V\in\cal V$ let $U_V=\{U\in\mathcal U\mid V\subseteq U\}$, using the axiom of countable choice, choose one from each set, and prove that it is an open cover.

Comment: will, that is the essence of the first paragraph. Yes.